# Skype for business call plugin

Tags: plugins, skype-for-business, ucma, skypedeveloper, ucwa

I am a beginner developer and I am looking to make a plugin in Skype for business (=SfB). This plugin is a component of the menu of the right click in the contact and this makes it possible to place the call via a telephone platform.
Can I find some examples (using UCMA) in the same context please?

Comment: Sorry : Skype4B Call Plugin

Comment: Hey, were you successful in adding a plugin in skype for business? Please follow up, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I personally would say it do not make any sense to develop such a plugin. The reason is that Skype for Business (=SfB) can perform that on its own. Its one of the key feature from Skype for Business and required a so called Plus CAL and for example a Session boarder controller ([e.g. Audiocodes Mediant 1000](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dn947483.aspx)) or an IP-PBX ([e.g. Avaya Aura Session Manager 6.1](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dn947483.aspx)) which connect SfB to a telephone platform.

[image]

Via that construct you can dial phone numbers directly via your Skype for Business client and also receive PSTN calls via Skype for Business.