# Call plugin for Skype for Business

Tags: user-interface, visual-c++, plugins, autohotkey, skype-for-business

I am trying to:

1. Use a program written in Visual C++ as a plugin in Skype for Business

**or**

2. Make the program window follow (attach itself to) the bottom of the Skype for Business user interface, using some type of tracker.

Any advice, or help on where to start?

I found the below links which would use Windows scripting tools such as AutoIt or AutoHotkey. I am not sure if this is the right approach.

https://www.reddit.com/r/AutoHotkey/comments/3ck7ak/tie_a_gui_to_a_window_ideas/
https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/120474-attaching-a-gui-to-another-window/

If it is the correct approach, then, where do I start? If it is not the correct approach, what else can I do?

**This question might seem as a duplicate to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45801608/skype-for-business-call-plugin). Yet, the question was discarded.**

Comment: Yes please! I would also like to know the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This AutoHotkey script allows you to attach a notepad window to an explorer window:

```
#Persistent
SetTimer, attach_window, 200 
Return 

    attach_window: 
IfWinNotExist ahk_class CabinetWClass ; explorer
    return ; do nothing
IfWinNotExist ahk_class Notepad
    return
; otherwise:
; retrieve the position and size of the explorer window:
WinGetPos, X, Y, Width, Height, ahk_class CabinetWClass
; attach the notepad window to the right side of the explorer window:
WinMove, ahk_class Notepad,, X+Width, Y
; To make the notepad window attach itself to the bottom of the explorer window use:
; WinMove, ahk_class Notepad,, X, Y+Height
Return
```

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinGetPos.htm

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinMove.htm

Use the included Window Spy utility to get various information about the windows you want use.